# why does this TableAdapter take so long to load?

Tags: vb.net

I've created a TableAdapter by dragging a data source onto a form and it fills a datagrid. The table with the data in it has 300,000 rows, I only want 5-10 in the datagrid. So I added a filter like this:

```
    Private Sub frmCertPremEdit_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lngID As Long
    If Not Long.TryParse(frmMain.txtCertID.Text, lngID) Then Exit Sub
    CertPremiumBindingSource.Filter = "CertID = " & lngID.ToString
    CertPremiumTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CertPremium._CertPremium)
```

There's a 5-10 second pause on the Adapter.Fill statement. The CertID is a primary key, other uses of this filter return an instantaneous result. It seems like something is wrong with what I'm doing.

Should this take 5-10 seconds? If not, what's the right way to do this?

Comment: Open Profiler to see actual queries being executed.
Profier will let you figure out what actual queries get executed and whether or not you are doing filtering on the server side.

Comment: How many rows actually end up in your `Me.CertPremium._CertPremium`?

Comment: Are you using paging for the rest of the records or are you wanting to only ever show those 5-10? If the latter why don't you change the query to only return those rows instead of handling it after the fact?

Comment: You are filtering in the `BindingSource`, which means that the table adapter is still going to load the entire 100k rows into the `DataTable`. If you don't want to retrieve all the records then you need to filter in the query, which means adding a query with a `WHERE` clause to your table adapter.

Comment: Got it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171905(v=vs.120).aspx